# GIT - unable to remove specific branch from remote repository

Tags: git

I cannot remove a remote branch called `origin/featureBranch`. I guess it's because the branch name starts with `origin`, but I am not sure:

```
$ git branch -r | grep featureBranch
  origin/origin/featureBranch

$ git push origin :origin/featureBranch

    error: unable to push to unqualified destination: origin/featureBranch

    The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
    begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.

    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:myCompany/my-repo.git'
```

**UPDATE**

`$ git push origin :featureBranch` gives the same error.

**NOTE**

In remote branch is `origin/origin/myFeature`, locally it is `origin/myFeature`.

I know what `origin` usually means, but in my case - this is part of name of the branch.

Github does not see this branch.

---

Could please anyone explain me what happens "behind the scene" and how can I remove this branch?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Sorry for my rudeness - didn't want to harm anybody. Changed description :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
git push origin :refs/heads/origin/featureBranch
```

You can always reference branches by their technical name under `refs/heads/`.

A branch is stored as a small text file under `.git/refs/`. Local branches go under `.git/refs/heads/`, and remote branches under `.git/refs/remotes/<remotename>/`. A simple branch like `master` will thus be found at `.git/refs/heads/master` and `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master`, but your buggy branch will actually reside under `.git/refs/heads/origin/featureBranch`. It will not be confused with a remote branch on the `origin` repository because it's not under `refs/remotes/origin/`, but under `refs/heads/`.

On the remote server, the `origin/featureBranch` branch is *local* to the server, so it will be stored under `refs/heads/`. When pushing to a given branch, you can identify it either by its name, or by its path, so if a name doesn't work, just use the full path starting with `refs`.

How you ended up with this weird branch name? I can't tell for sure, since I don't know what you did, but I encountered the same problem when I used `git push --mirror`, which pushes all the references, **including** remote ones, so it will create an `origin/branchname` as a **local** branch.

Comment: `How you ended up with this weird branch name?` I am working on project with lot of developers. Someone created this weird name, I don't know - who, how and why :)

Comment: @thecatontheflat Oh I've seen this happen a half dozen times. Someone wanted to inspect origin's `featureBranch` branch but used `git checkout` instead of `git log`, then probably issued `git push` with a `push.default` setting he or she didn't understand. It's a pretty common error in new git users.

Comment: I accidentally created this by doing `git push origin myBranch:origin/master` or something, and your suggestion solved my issue (with the addition of an extra "origin/" for some reason)!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$ git push origin :featureBranch
```

You already specified where to push, the `origin/` is only the name of your local branch.

Background: When git does a fetch, it creates so called 'remote tracking branches'. 
Those don't really differ from your own branches, they are simply prefixed with the remote name (origin/master for example) and represent the server branches locally (all commits have already been fetched).

When you do a push origin you are not referring at all to your local remote tracking branches but rather tell Git "push to origin sourcebranch:targetbranch"

Comment: See my question more careful - the branch name starts from `origin`, not the remote repository. In remote it is `origin/origin/myFeature`

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see that. 
In that case I'd just login to the server and remove the branch locally. You can go into a bare cloned repo and do git branch -D etc..

Answer (score 1):

This bit of the message says it can't find any matching branch.

```
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
```

It's what I get if I try to delete the branch twice. (The first succeeds, and the second fails).
Or if the branch has been deleted by someone else. You could try `git remote prune` and see if it disapears from your `git branch -r` output. You could also check the branch is on `origin` using `git ls-remote git@github.com:myCompany/my-repo.git`.

Deleting oddly (badly?) named branches like `origin/master` on `origin` works just fine for me:

```
$ git push origin master:origin/master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 218 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To ../bare/
 * [new branch]      master -> origin/master

$ git branch -r
  origin/origin/master

$ git push origin :origin/master
To ../bare/
 - [deleted]         origin/master
```

Comment: It depends on the git version. I know that it used to fail several months ago, but indeed it seems to work now.

Comment: For the record my git is 1.7.3.2 (not really new, but not ancient either)

Comment: I had problems with 1.6.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

Simply drop `origin` behind the colon:

`git push origin :featureBranch`

As Michael explains, it means to push "nothing" to the named branch.
[Here](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html) is a more complete explanation.